# Netlogo Web run time error

Tags: netlogo

I am running my model ok in Netlogo desktop. But when I run it on the web it will report this error when I click the setup button:

> turtle.getBreedName is not a function

Anyone who knows the root cause of this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question to include the smallest model that generates the error.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry the model is for commercial purpose and I have signed NDA with my client. And I dont know where is wrong because I can run it ok in Netlogo Desktop

Comment: Hey Jerry, you can email your model to bugs@ccl.northwestern.edu, where we'll keep it private, or you can try to provide a more detailed description of what the model is doing so we know where to look for the issue.

Comment: Dear Jasper, I already sent out the email containing the file two days ago. But there is not response. Could you check it for me? I have a client meeting on Friday and I want to make model demo with my client using Netlogo web

Comment: Hey Jerry, can you please try emailing the model again and include "NetLogo" in the title?  I don't see it in the queue.

Comment: For anyone else who might find this:  The issue is with using a custom breed (like `breed [apples apple]`) along with an out-of-range `who` number (like `apple -1`).  In desktop this gives `nobody`, but in NetLogo Web it's throwing an error.  This will be fixed in an upcoming release.